# Unable to UPDATE values in SQLite table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, sqlite

I have a cross platform app created using AngularJS, Monaca and OnsenUI. For the app I have a SQLite database implemented.

I can create a table and I can insert values into it, but I am having trouble updating rows in the table.

What I have done is create a table and then insert an initial value (ID) into it. As the user interacts with a form on the view, I need to UPDATE the column values in the created table WHERE the ID exists.

My function in **app.js** that gets the selected options from the views form looks as below.

```
$scope.myID = "";
$scope.changedValue = function (selectedValue) // The value selected on the views Form
{
    $scope.myID = selectedValue;
    insertIntoDatabase($scope.myID, "tb_my_table", "my_id");
    break;
}
```

And my function for *insertIntoDatabase(...)*.

```
function insertIntoDatabase(value, tableName, columnName)
{
    var sql = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ' + tableName + ' (' + columnName + ') VALUES (?)'; // WORKING
    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql, [value]); }); // WORKING
    break;
}
```

This works as intended and I can see the inserted values when I query the table.

But what I need to do then is UPDATE the rows in the table following the initial insert based on user selected options from the view.

I have a similar function for updating the table that also gets called (via omitted switch-statement) from the *changedValue* function.

Method call to UPDATE:

```
updateDatabase($scope.myValue, "tb_my_table", "my_val");
```

And my function to UPDATE the table row:

```
function updateDatabase(value, tableName, columnName)
{
    var sql = 'UPDATE ' + tableName + ' SET ' + columnName + ' VALUES (?) WHERE my_id = "' + $scope.myID + '"'; // NOT WORKING - NULL
    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql, [value]); }); // NOT WORKING - NULL
    break;
}
```

So Im trying to update the table with a new column value where the id is the same as the initial ID. Is there an error in the syntac or is there another issue? No errors are thrown by the debugger - all I get when I query the column *my_val* is NULL.

Comment: Without the [correct syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html), you should get an error.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. But no errors thrown - the vlaue is simply NULL.